# htaccess redirect to certain page depending on condition

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following urls:

www.mydomain.com/contacto.html
www.mydomain.com/pedidos.html
www.mydomain.com/quienes.html

I want to redirect them to:
www.mydomain.com/

I have wrote the following script, but it is not working ok.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(contacto\.html|pedidos\.html|quienes\.html)$     
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
```

Do you have any idea how to make this thing working?

Thanks in advance,
Emanuel

Comment: What does it mean "not working ok"? Have you checked your error logs? Where are those rules, are they in an htaccess file and if so where is that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the first time I see the problem here. I do not know why. 
But I know it works like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(contacto\.html|pedidos\.html|quienes\.html)$     
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Delete your cache or try from other browser if it does not work the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Croises,

I've used something very similar to what you has suggested.
I did the following:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(home|pedidos|quienes|contacto).html$ 
RewriteRule .* / [R=301,L]

Thank you very much for your help.

BR